# Passing command line arguments for spark.read.json from HDFS path

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hdfs, hadoop2

I am trying to load some json files from hdfs using spark.read.json. When I am hardcoding the path as `"hdfs://ha-cluster-dev/test/inputs/*"` and submiting the jar using spark-submit, then it works perfectly OK.

I then try to pass this path using command lines. I wrote below piece of code:

```
object Two {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val conf = new Configuration()
    conf.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://ha-cluster-dev")
    val fs = FileSystem.get(new URI("hdfs://ha-cluster-dev"), conf)
    val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("Count").getOrCreate()
    import spark.implicits._
    val input = fs.open(new Path(args(0)))
    val df = spark.read.json(input.toString()) 

...my operations.....
}
}
```

And used below spark submit command:

```
/home/hadoop/spark/bin/spark-submit --class com.spark.scala.Two --files hdfs://ha-cluster-dev/test/inputs/* --master yarn --deploy-mode client Spark-Scala-0.0.1.jar.
```

It gives :

```
 17/07/16 09:09:30 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://ha-cluster-dev/test/inputs/*
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Hdfs.getFileStatus(Hdfs.java:134)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.AbstractFileSystem.resolvePath(AbstractFileSystem.java:467)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext$25.next(FileContext.java:2193)
....
....
....
```

Tried with `hdfs://`, without `hdfs://`, without `--files` but nothing works. Where am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Earlier with above state, the job was not even accepted. I changed the spark-submit command to /home/hadoop/spark/bin/spark-submit --class com.spark.scala.Two  --master yarn --deploy-mode client Spark-Scala-0.0.1.jar hdfs://ha-cluster-dev/test/inputs/*.    Now the job came into accepted and then running state, but gave same error as :- Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: /test/inputs/*

Comment: spark.read.json expects a string.. why pass an argument to app and use that argument as string (spark.read.json(args[0]). the Path is redundant